# How to populate chart with data from database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm following this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts-graphs-revised) to create a chart of data. It recommends I do the following:

orders.js

```
jQuery ->
  Morris.Line
    element: 'orders_chart'
    data: $('#orders_chart').data('orders')
    xkey: 'purchased_at'
    ykeys: ['price', 'shipping_price', 'download_price']
    labels: ['Total Price', 'Shipping Price', 'Download Price']
    preUnits: '$'
```

And then create an element in the view, with a table also in the view which fills the graph. However, I would like the data not to be `$('#orders_chart').data('orders')`, but rather data directly from the database so that the table doesn't get shown on the webpage. How would I do that?

Comment: To do what you want, you need to make an ajax request, after you receive the data just send it to `Morris data:`. Anyway, I don't understand what table do you see in the view?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

Set a route in your routes files that will give you the json data:

```
get '/get_graph_data', to: 'graphs#data_show', as: 'get_graph_data', defaults: {format: 'json'}
```

Step 2:

Write you controller

```
class GraphsController
  def data_show
    get the json data
  end
end
```

Write the ajax get request

```
get_graph_data = ->
  url = (you can use a data-tag to get the url from your view)
  $.ajax
    type: 'get'
    url: url
    dataType: 'json'
    success: (json) ->
      send_data_to_morris or another method to change it if necessary
```